# Create table not visible in code ( Xamarin )

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have a piece of code in Xamarin that takes the Json output from my own server. And that output I want to put in a table.

This is my code so far and the logger shows the Json perfecty fine

```
public class Application
{
    // This is the main entry point of the application.
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        // Create a request for the URL. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
            "http://10.190.80.248/WebService/webservice.asmx/getStudentID?id=1");
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        // Display the content.
        Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams and the response.


        // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
        // you can specify it here.
        UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");


    }
}
```

Yet there is one problem. The table I want to put the Json code into, is called "SchoolTable" but no matter what I try the table does not show up in code. Normally when I type Sc, it would auto fill in Schooltable. But not now.

**How can I get my table to be visible in code and use it to store the Json data into it?**

Comment: so you have a code autocompletion problem or what?

Comment: No, somehow you have to do something in Xamarin ( like link table and code ) before autocompletion works. I miss that " link ". And I can't seem to fix it

Comment: Why are you putting all of this code in Main.cs?  The UI has not been initialized at that point and will not be accessible.  Xamarin has dozens of tutorials and sample apps you can review to see how to properly structure an app and use TableViews.